# Solving a particular Fourier transfrom

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I am trying to find the Fourier transform of the expression
$e^{-\nu |t-s|}$, which is given in a number of places (such as [here](http://www.physik.uni-augsburg.de/theo1/hanggi/Papers/160.pdf), pg. 248) as being $\frac{\nu}{\omega^2+\nu^2}$. However I get a very different answer:

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\nu |t-s|}e^{-i \omega t}dt
  &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\nu |u|-i \omega (u+s)}du
    \quad\textrm{with $u=t-s$}\\
  &=\int_0^\infty e^{-u(\nu+i \omega)-i\omega s}du+\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{u(\nu-i \omega)-i \omega s}du\\
  &=\left[ \frac{-1}{\nu+i \omega}e^{-u(\nu+i\omega)-i\omega s}\right]_0^\infty+\left[\frac{1}{\nu-i\omega}e^{u(\nu-i\omega)-i\omega s}\right]^0_{-\infty} \\
&=e^{-i\omega s}\left( \frac{1}{\nu+i\omega}+\frac{1}{\nu-i\omega} \right)
\end{align}
Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Note that if referring to the link, I have used $D=1$ and $\nu=1/\tau$.

Comment: Maybe the definition of Fourier transform used there has $e^{-i\omega t}$ instead?

Comment: Nothing went wrong.  You have the correct answer.  Simply get a common denominator.

Comment: @GEdgar, that was a typo on my part, now fixed to $-i\omega s$.

Comment: @Dr.MV, if I do that, I get $e^{-i\omega s} \frac{\nu}{\nu^2+\omega^2}$. This goes over to the desired answer in the limit that $s=0$, but none of the sources which give this result state this as an assumption. Physically, I'm not sure it would be justified.

Comment: Your answer is correct and the appearance of the "phase" term $e^{-i\omega s}$ is an immediate consequence of the time shift $t-s$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference you cite studies the spectrum of:
$$
  \frac{D}{\tau} e^{ - |t-s|/\tau }
$$

From your proposed solution (taking $D=1$ and $\nu=1/\tau$), this leads to:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \nu\ e^{-\nu |t-s| }e^{-i\omega t} dt 
  &= \nu\ e^{-i\omega s} \left( \frac{1}{\nu + i\omega} + \frac{1}{\nu - i\omega} \right) \\
  &= \nu\ e^{-i\omega s} \frac{ \nu - i\omega + \nu + i\omega }{ (\nu + i\omega) (\nu - i\omega) } \\
  &= e^{-i\omega s} \frac{ 2\nu^2 }{ \nu^2 + \omega^2 }
\end{align}

Which corresponds to the result proposed in your reference:
$$
  \frac{2D}{\tau^2\omega^2+1}
$$

Maybe what bothers you is that this is only the magnitude of the power spectrum; I think this is simply an abusive language from the book (the magnitude of the power spectrum is often what people think about when talking about the "power spectrum" of a 1d signal). The [Wiener-Khinchin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem) relates the PSD to the autocorrelation function via:
$$
  R(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty S(\nu)\ e^{i\nu t}\ d\nu
$$
so clearly if $R(t)$ should be real, then $S(\nu)$ should be complex.

Comment: Thanks. There's a further thing which bothers me about this: The magnitude of the power spectrum ought to be real, and it seems the only way to get this is to confine ourselves to $s=0$. Perhaps that's ok, but it's not mentioned in the reference I've given or anywhere else that I've found an equivalent result. Further, if we were to take $s\neq 0$, then we'd have to have $D(\omega)$, instead of a constant $D$, which would really change the character of the spectrum.

Comment: @DanGoldwater I find it confusing as well, when reading online sources, but I think my edit clarifies the situation with the Wiener-Khinchin theorem.